# discord.js "awaitReactions" event not functional?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Below is a small section from the code, if you need more to understand the issue then let me know. The code runs and outputs "stuff applied.. awaiting.", but when a reaction is added nothing happens.

```js
let PossibleMessage = await Message.channel.send({embeds: [msgEmbed1]});

PossibleMessage.react("✅").then(() => {
  PossibleMessage.react("❎").then(() => {
    console.log("stuff applied.. awaiting.")
    PossibleMessage.awaitReactions(
      (Reaction, User) => User.id == Message.author.id && (Reaction.emoji.name == "❎" || Reaction.emoji.name == "✅"),
      {max: 1, time: 3000}

    ).then(Collected => {
      console.log("yes")
      if (Collected.first().emoji.name == "✅") {
        console.log("ye2")
```

Comment: mixing `await`  and `.then` in one function always makes me suspicious, and nesting those `.react.then` looks odd too

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using (works fine on v12)?

Comment: Have you enabled the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` or (`DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` for DMs) intent?

Comment: Use lowercase variable names for everything that is not a class (constructor) or a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine (the code you shared miss the 3 ending "}").

Maybe the time you have insterted in the options is too fast and the event ends without get any response.
Try with `{max: 1, time: 10000}` to make the listener wait for 10 seconds.

If you are using discord.js v13 make sure You have anabled the intents for reactions like that:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS] });
```